# How to check Contains big string into small string?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

I have SQL Server data base where i am storing city Name. Like "Delhi";

```
Example: I have samll word "delhi"
```

and collection of big string is  "New Delhi", "Old Delhi", "Delhi ncr".

If I will make search any serach from big string then it will return all data from delhi city.

Please let me how can i do this.

I am using `Linq to sql` and `linq queries`.

**My First Edit**

In my table column City Saved as "delhi".

if I will make any search query like this "New Delhi","New delhi","Old Delhi" "Old delhi" or "delhi ncr" all should be return all data of "delhi" city.

Please suggest me query for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this out !!!

```
var result = City.Where(s=>s.cityName.ToLower().contains("delhi")).ToList();
```

Edited Answer

```
var result = City.Where(s => s.Name.ToLower().Split(' ').Contains("delhi")).ToList();
```

hope this helps !!!!

Comment: Thanks For Your Reply but this not I am looking for. I am editing My Question. Please check and help me.

Comment: Try the updated code once ... may be this could solve ur problem

Answer (score 1):

If you want a case-insensitive search, just use

```
String.Equals("delhi", "Delhi", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

in your linq query.

Comment: Thanks For Your Reply but this not I am looking for. I am editing My Question. Please check and help me.